# What is mstreamd in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

every one
I have some question
Can someone tell me , iPhone to doing what?
What is it "mstreamd"?
What is it "Media stream"?
Why mstreamd would work? and it will affect the Bluetooth connection device ?

Thank you in advance!

iPhone log:

```
May 28 15:10:07 iPhone-5 mstreamd[52474] <Notice>: (Note ) mstreamd: Not monitoring for external power. 
May 28 15:10:07 iPhone-5 mstreamd[52474] <Notice>: (Note ) PS: Media stream daemon stopping. 
May 28 15:10:07 iPhone-5 mstreamd[52474] <Notice>: (Note ) AS: <MSIOSAlbumSharingDaemon: 0x155349f0>: Shared Streams daemon has shut down. 
May 28 15:10:07 iPhone-5 mstreamd[52474] <Notice>: (Warn ) mstreamd: mstreamd shutting down. 
May 28 15:10:07 iPhone-5 mstreamd[52475] <Notice>: (Note ) mstreamd: mstreamd starting up. 
May 28 15:10:07 iPhone-5 mstreamd[52475] <Notice>: (Note ) PS: Media stream daemon starting...
```

Comment: 我知道了！
http://weicdsq.lofter.com/post/20a5c5_14ebf2e http://bbs.feng.com/read-htm-tid-6212522.html

Answer (score 3):

It's the daemon that controls Photo Stream.  I don't know if it would affect Bluetooth devices,  but as it controls Photo Stream I don't think it would.